# Change to desiredCapabilities in beforeEach not reflecting

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am trying to record all browser request and responses. This can be done via browsermob-proxy api's.

For this, I have to change desired capabilities and change httpProxy for browser.

In beforeEach at global or file level, I am trying to change this. Though it reflects in browser object, actual browser is not initiated with those settings.

Simple example:

globalhook file

```
module.exports = {
 before : function (done) {

},

beforeEach: function(browser, done){

 browser.options.desiredCapabilities = {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "proxy": {
          "proxyType": "manual",
          "httpProxy": "127.0.0.1:" + someport,
          "sslProxy": "127.0.0.1:" + someport
        },
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
 }
done()
},

afterEach: function(browser, done){
 //some code
}

after : function (done) {
 //some code
},

}
```

If i change desired capabilities in before hook, chrome browser is taking those changes. Problem is with beforeEach [global, file level].

Further debugging, I've found setCapabilities function is run just before beforeEach Hook.

[image]

Could anyone please have a look or suggest if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: For folks having this problem, Solution is in update comment given by @akrn. That worked for me. Unfortunately, I could not upvote and accept as answer as i am not still eligible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for moving the issue here.

The issue is that the `desiredCapabilities` are applied to a browser session.
`beforeEach` and `afterEach` run on the same browser session therefore any change in the `desiredCapabilities` won't be applied unless the session is restarted.

If you need to dynamically change the `desiredCapabilities` you have to structure your tests in the different way, e.g. split your tests in separate test classes

Comment: Yes. I have separate test classes. File mentioned in above query is global hook and I have beforeEach and afterEach at file level. I am maintaining only one test per file.

Here is flow for each testcase/testfile run:




before (from global hook) -> beforeEach (from global hook) -> beforeEach (testfile level) -> Test execution -> afterEach  (testfile level) -> afterEach (from global hook) -> after (from global hook)

Comment: In that case you just need to put the desiredCapabilities change under before (from global hook)

Comment: Tat is the exact problem. If I change in desired capabilities in global before hook, I cannot run tests parallel. I have to run only in series as port will be busy if I try to run parallel. Is their any other way around??

Comment: How are you running the tests in parallel?

Comment: I am using testworkers given by nightwatch. Update which akrn mentioned above did the trick. I have to just change proxy in beforeEach(testfile level) not entire desiredCapabilities obj. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably want to use `before()` hook instead of `beforeEach()`, since `beforeEach()` will run before each test case and you won't be able to modify already started browser session. `before()` will run before browser session is initiated.

To solve your issue you need to define `desiredCapabilities` property on your test run module and in case you need to set some dynamic values, use `before()` hook to modify that object:

```
module.exports = {
  desiredCapabilities: {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "proxy": {
        "proxyType": "manual",
        "httpProxy": "127.0.0.1",
        "sslProxy": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "acceptSslCerts": true,
  },

  before: function(client, done) {
    this.desiredCapabilities.proxy.sslProxy = '127.0.0.1' + someport;
    done();
  }
}
```

I've searched official docs on this feature but couldn't find anything, though we used this in our tests and it worked well.

**Update:**

Since you only need to change `proxy` on `desiredCapabilities` object, there is a little hack:

```
// global hooks file:
module.exports = {
  beforeEach: function(client, done) {
    client.options.desiredCapabilities.proxy = {
      "proxyType": "manual",
      "httpProxy": "127.0.0.1:" + someport,
      "sslProxy": "127.0.0.1:" + someport
    };
    done(client);
  }
};
```

Changing `desiredCapabilities` object won't work, since reference to original object is already stored somewhere under the hood of Nightwatch. But nothing stops you from overriding `proxy` property on that object.

After checking sources and tests in Nightwatch I believe this is the only solution for your case.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have global before() hook which executed at first for all suite execution. Are you suggesting to use another before() hook at test file level? Even with this case, "this.desiredCapabilities" is not available. It should have been "this.options.desiredCapabilities". Pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Rajesh Check update, there is a hack which should help you

Comment: Changing only proxy was the trick. I wonder why i did not think that way. Thanks a lot.